# Multiple response http status in Spring MVC

Tags: jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

Having the following code:

```
@RequestMapping(value =  "/system/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void login(@RequestBody Login login) {
    if(login.username == "test" && login.password == "test") {
         //return HTTP 200
    }
    else {
         //return HTTP 400
    }
}
```

I would like to return two different HTTP statuses based on my logic. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: I guess I have found a working way, what you have to do is add the HttpServletResponse response inside the method, last argument and then simply set the setStatus.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One approach which someone suggested at SO is to throw different exceptions which will be catch by different exception handlers:

```
@RequestMapping(value =  "/system/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void login(@RequestBody Login login) {
    if(login.username == "test" && login.password == "test") {
         throw new AllRightException();
    }
    else {
         throw new AccessDeniedException();
    }
}

@ExceptionHandler(AllRightException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public void whenAllRight() {

}

@ExceptionHandler(AccessDeniedException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public void whenAccessDenied() {

}
```

See also:

- [@ExceptionHandler](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-exceptionhandler)
- [@ResponseStatus](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ResponseStatus.html)

BTW, your example code contains error: `login.password == "test"` you should use `equals()` there :)

---

**Updated**: I found another approach which even better because it doesn't use exceptions:

```
@RequestMapping(value =  "/system/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<String> login(@RequestBody Login login) {
    if(login.username == "test" && login.password == "test") {
         return new ResponseEntity<String>("OK" HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<String>("ERROR", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

See also [ResponseEntity API](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html)

Comment: Thanks for that error, but that was just a java-pseudo-code like.

Comment: You can even return JSon with **@ResponseBody** using **ResponseEntity**.

Comment: Though it´s an old question, I think I should remark that using Exceptions for 200 is not a good idea... Every time you think of an AlrightException you should probably think of an alternative. In this particular case, the most common way is to handle the success flow in the main flow and throw a AccessDeniedException if it´s a invalid credential.