# Using both @RequestBody and @RequestParam together in spring mvc3

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using spring-mvc **3.1.0.RELEASE** and for some reason, mapping POST with query params and request body does not work.

Here is how my controller method looks:

```
  @RequestMapping(method = POST, value = "/post-to-me/") 
  public void handlePost(
    @RequestBody Content content,
    @RequestParam("param1") String param1,
    @RequestParam("param2") String param2
  ){
       //do stuff       
  }
```

However, if I convert all the request params to path params, mapping works. Has anyone run into something similar?

Thanks!

EDIT:
 "does not work" == 404 when I try doing, `POST /post-to-me?param1=x&param2=y`

Comment: Does it work, if you remove `@RequestParam("param1") String param1` and `param2` too?

Comment: what content-type does your request have and what content type it accepts in response?

Comment: i have the same problem but Error is 500 ... have you solved your problem?

Comment: Did you annotate your class with @Controller or @RestController? I tried your code and it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

First, your POST url doen't match the controller method url, your POST url must be "/post-to-me/?param1=x&param2=y" not "/post-to-me?param1=x&param2=y"

Second, where did Content class come from?? I used a String and works fine for me

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/post-to-me/")
public void handlePost(@RequestBody String content,
        @RequestParam("param1") String param1,
        @RequestParam("param2") String param2, HttpServletResponse response) {
    System.out.println(content);
    System.out.println(param1);
    System.out.println(param2);
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
}
```

Note that I used HttpServletResponse to return a HTTP 200 code, but I think there is a better solution for return Http codes, check this: [Multiple response http status in Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474957/multiple-response-http-status-in-spring-mvc)

Answer (score 1):

Trailing slash at the end of your request mapping value might be the problem.
Try:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/post-to-me")
```

or send your POST request to `POST /post-to-me/?param1=x&param2=y`